# Find whether a computer is using 24 hour or 12 hour time format in C#

Tags: c#

Existing code of my application

```
  ` public static string FormatTime()
    {
       return DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToLongTimeString();
    }`
```

This code always returns time in 12hr format even when my computer shows time in 24hr format. I want to show time in my application in same format as computer's clock shows time.

I need this time settings. 
[my computer time is set to display in 24hr format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OQBh.png)

If the users computer time is set to display in 24hr format, my application should display time in 24hr format. If the time is set to display in 12hr format, my application should display time in 12hr format.

Comment: The computer itself doesn't use 12 hour or 24 hour time. It just knows time. It's only when some program decides to present the time in a digital format that the "12 hour" or "24 hour" comes into play, and that's determined by user settings. So what you're really asking is for someone to guess what "computer clock" program you're talking about and then to tell you how to find and read that program's settings. You would be better off just letting the user control the 12/24 hour setting directly in your own program.

Comment: SO users that ask localization questions should *always* complete their profile so we can tell what part of the world they live in.

Comment: I have searched more about this but I couldn't get any correct methods.Could someone provide any information on this?